# patch in serializer django rest

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, patch

I have 1 parent and 1 child serializers, right now child serializer inherits all fields, functions and methods from the parent serializer.
I would like to modify patch request in child serializer, that while request is patch, then some
fields will be unavailable for updating, cause there will be completely different two urls.
For example in child class there will be unable to update name and surname.

```
class Parent(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseMeta):
        model = Account
        fields = BaseMeta.fields + (
                'name', 'surname', 'age', 'city', 'country', 'job', 'family')
     
        extra_kwargs = {'name': {'required': True, 'allow_blank': False, 'allow_null': False, 'trim_whitespace': False},
                'surname': {'required': True, 'allow_blank': False, 'allow_null': False, 'trim_whitespace': False},
                'country': {'read_only': True},
                'job': {'required': True, 'allow_blank': False, 'allow_null': False, },
            }

class Child(ParentSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseMeta):
        model = Account
        fields = BaseMeta.fields + ()
     
        extra_kwargs = {
            }
```

Comment: You can make use of [to_representation and to_internal_value functions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement `PATCH` api, you can create a detail view.

```
from rest_framework import generics, mixins
from .models import Child
from .serializers import Child as ChildSerializer

class ChildDetail(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Child.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChildSerializer
    
    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In the detail view, you can also add `get`, `retrieve`, `put`, `delete` method.